# How do I attach a email entry to a button when using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to creating a subscribe button that allows customers to enter their emails like shown in the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDBfy.jpg

```
      <div class="signup text-center">
          <h4>JOIN OUR MAILING LIST!</h4>
              <input type="email" id="myEmail" value="enter your email">
              <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-light-orange btn-sign">SUBSCRIBE</button> 




         .btn.btn-sign{
          padding: 1px 15px;

          border-radius: 0;
          font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
          font-size: 20px;
          font-weight: 600;
```

Comment: Please post all of the relevant markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming you're using Bootstrap 4.X*, if you create a `<div class="input-group">` that surrounds your `input` and `button`, then this creates the outcome you wanted.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="signup text-center">
     <h4>JOIN OUR MAILING LIST!</h4>
     <div class="input-group justify-content-center">
         <input type="email" id="myEmail" value="enter your email">
         <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-light-orange btn-sign">SUBSCRIBE</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:** *Nothing changed here*

```
.btn.btn-sign{
    padding: 1px 15px;

    border-radius: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

[Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/#button-addons) to Bootstrap's example of Button Addons for an `input-group`

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dqLg3wpe/) is a JSFiddle example if you need it

Comment: I also see the Bootstrap 3.X also has this functionality as well.